# How can I change my routers management interface from port 80 to port 81

Tags: router, ssh, port-forwarding, port

I have a TL-WR1043 router and I want to port forward a webserver on port 80 but the router is in the way.

So how can I change the router management interface from port 80 to port 81?

I heard that custom firmware can do it but I am afraid to screw up the installation so is there a way from the original management interface or from the SSH console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this matters. Port forwarding is doing just that, forwarding a port to another machine. If you Port Forward port 80 to another machine on your network you're telling the router to forward all packets destined for port 80 coming into your network to that machine. You shouldn't need to change the management interface port on your router to port forward port 80 to another machine.